# Are there any known issues with the Jupyter Notebook and md5sum?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pipe

Is there a step I've missed to enable the notebook to use a pipe and return a md5sum on a provided file?

Currently it does not function correctly on my computer(Mac) for the example below from the book *Think Python*

```
def pipe(cmd):
     """Runs a command in a subprocess.

     cmd: string Unix command

     Returns (res, stat), the output of the subprocess and the exit status.
"""
     # Note: os.popen is deprecated
     # now, which means we are supposed to stop using it and start using
     # the subprocess module.  But for simple cases, I find
     # subprocess more complicated than necessary.  So I am going
     # to keep using os.popen until they take it away.

     fp = os.popen(cmd)
     res = fp.read()
     stat = fp.close()
     assert stat is None
     return res, stat

cmd= 'md5sum ' + 'words.txt'
pipe(cmd)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-ccd8fd0ce9f8> in <module>
     18     return res, stat
     19 cmd= 'md5sum ' + 'words.txt'
---> 20 pipe(cmd)

<ipython-input-137-ccd8fd0ce9f8> in pipe(cmd)
     15     res = fp.read()
     16     stat = fp.close()
---> 17     assert stat is None
     18     return res, stat
     19 cmd= 'md5sum ' + 'words.txt'

AssertionError:
```

Comment: Did anything come after `AssertionError: `? If you run `md5sum words.txt; echo $?` manually from the shell, what do you see?

Comment: i get the following when doing that ***-bash: md5sum: command not found   127***

Comment: after looking into this some more it looks like MacOS by default does not come with md5sum installed but offers a essentially similar tool md5 which returns the hash.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica thank you. It was really helpful to see it from the shell itself. Far to often I have run the assumption that if my book hasn't mentioned needing an extra component that the issues lie with me the operator and not with missing components. This was a good reminder to test at all levels not just my own input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*answering myself below*

I have realized this issue is not with the Jupyter Notebook itself. Mac OS X, does not come with md5sum installed by default, however it offers an equivalent tool, md5. To calculate the 128 bit MD5 hash of a file, run this command:

md5 file.ext

the command returns the 128bit md5 hash

The code initially used above would now look like this.

```
def pipe(cmd):
     """Runs a command in a subprocess.

     cmd: string Unix command

     Returns (res, stat), the output of the subprocess and the exit status.
"""
     # Note: os.popen is deprecated
     # now, which means we are supposed to stop using it and start using
     # the subprocess module.  But for simple cases, I find
     # subprocess more complicated than necessary.  So I am going
     # to keep using os.popen until they take it away.

     fp = os.popen(cmd)
     res = fp.read()
     stat = fp.close()
     assert stat is None
     return res, stat

cmd= 'md5 ' + 'words.txt'
pipe(cmd)
```